# Python 2.7 Django 1.9 I can't pass 2 parameters

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I got an error message: "submission() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" and I suspect that I didn't pass the 2 parameters successfully.  I have struggled it for over 2 days now. Can anyone give me a quick diagnosis of what went wrong?

Here is my submission.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'submission' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
{% csrf_token %} 
<div>  
  <td>{{ form.title.label_tag }}</td>  
  <td>{{ form.title }}</td>  
</div>  
<div>  
  <td>{{ form.message.label_tag }}</td>  
  <td>{{ form.message }}</td>  
</div>  
<div> 
  <input type="text" name="image_id"  /> 
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />  
  <input type="submit" value="Store Post" />  

</div>
<a href="/discussion/registration">Register for an account</a><br>
<a href="/login">Login</a><br>
<a href="/logout/">Logout</a><br>
<a href="/discussion/">See All Comments</a><br>
<a href="/discussion/submission/">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Here is part of my view.py.  the purpose is trying to upload image files.

```
def submission(request, image_id):
    form = PostForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() == True:
            post_to_submit = Post()
            post_to_submit.post_title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            post_to_submit.post_text = form.cleaned_data['message']
            post_to_submit.pub_date = datetime.datetime.now()
            post_to_submit.user = request.user
            post_to_submit.save()
            image = Image.objects.get(id=image_id)
            image.comments.add(post_to_submit)
            template = loader.get_template('discussion/index.html')
            post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date') 
            context = {'post_list': post_list, 'image_id' : image_id}
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors.__str__())
    elif request.user.is_authenticated() and request.method != 'POST':
        form = PostForm()
        template = loader.get_template('discussion/submission.html')
        context = {'form' : form, 'image_id' : image_id}
    elif request.user.is_authenticated() == False:
        template = loader.get_template('registration/login.html')
        context = {}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request, {'image':image}))
```

Comment: Can you add `urls.py` also?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that will only get the issue that you have posted, because I see many bugs in your codes... The structure is not good. Explanations

> Hopefully this will help you spot out where you've messed up in your codes.

**1) User Authenticated / Request.GET**: redirect to submission template with `form` and `id` as variables. In that templates, the form `action` needs a required argument `image_id` because it's shown clearly in `def submission(request, image_id):`.
By this link `<a href="/discussion/submission/">Submit</a>`, I actually realize that you did not set your urls to receive any arguments.
`return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request, {'image':image}))` will generate `NameError: name 'image' is not defined`

**2) User Not Authenticated / Any Request**: you render the template `registration/login.html` with no context variables.
In that case 
this line `return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request, {'image':image}))` will generate `NameError: name 'image' is not defined`

**3) User Authenticated / Request.POST**: when the user submit the form.
you will not get any error if form is valid, because the `image` variable exists:

```
'''your codes'''
image = Image.objects.get(id=image_id)
image.comments.add(post_to_submit)
```

**Possible ways to fix the issue posted**

you can send the `image_id` through context and send it back via an hidden input inside the form rather than via form action url. No need to have argument in your view. `def submission(request)`:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ image_id }}" name="image_id" />
```

In case you need the image_id inside the url, just set up your urls.py properly by adding the regex argument, and edit your form action url by adding the `image_id` argument

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'submission' image_id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```